# Swarm stack is deployed before the new images are pushed

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-swarm, circleci, docker-registry

I use **CircleCI** and the *pipeline* is as follows:

- build
- test
- build `app` & `nginx` **Docker images** and push them to a **GitLab registry**
- deploy  **Docker stack** to the development server (currently the *Swarm manager*)

I just pushed my `develop` branch to my repository and faced a *"Symfony4 new Controller page"* on the development server after a successful message from **CircleCI**.

I logged via SSH in it and executed (with output for the application service):

```
docker stack ps my-development-stack  --format "{{.Name}} {{.Image}} {{.CurrentState}}"

my-stack_app.1    gitlab-image:latest-develop    Running 33 minutes ago
```

On my **GitLab** repository's registry, the application image has been *"Last Updated"* `41 minutes ago`. The service's image has apparently been *refreshed* before with the last version.

- Is it a common issue/error ?
- How could (or *should*) I fix this timing issue ?
- Can **CircleCI** help about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is best ( though not ideal ) to introduce a delay between build and deploy , you can refer to this example here [CircelCI Delay Between Jobs](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/delays-between-jobs-in-a-workflow/25135)

Comment: As a pipeline should not exceed a certain amount of time, this could work. A nightly deploy could do the trick too but I think these solutions are just workarounds, not technical solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you can try this as well https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#push-events

Comment: These are push webhooks for gitlab repositories, not for pushing to a registry. I only use gitlab for the registry, the application git repository is elsewhere

Comment: I found [registry webhooks](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18293) but it still isn't implemented :-/

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using a **CircleCI** scheduled workflow triggered by a **CRON**. I scheduled a *nightly build* workflow which will run every day at midnight.

Sample of my `config.yml` file

```
# Beginning of the config.yml
# ...

workflows:
    version: 2

    # Push workflow
    # ...

    # Nightly build workflow
    nightly-dev-deploy:
        triggers:
            - schedule:
                  cron: "0 0 * * *"
                  filters:
                      branches:
                          only:
                              - develop
        jobs:
            - build
            - test:
                requires:
                    - build
            - deploy-dev:
                requires:
                    - test
```

> Read more about scheduled workflow with a nightly build example in the [CircleCI official documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#scheduling-a-workflow)

---

*Looks more like a workaround to me. I'd be glad to hear how do you avoid this issue, which could lead to a better answer to the question.*